# substring_index does not take exact prefix

Tags: mysql, select, substring

I have a table contains strings. Some of them starts with `https://` and some starts with `http://`. I want to extract those that starts with `http://` (without `s`). Please note I do not want to use `LIKE` statement because of another conflict in my plan to treat this string. So if I have the following items in a column called `mycol` in `mytable`:

```
https://111.com/
https://www.222.com/en-gb/
```

I make this query:

```
SELECT `mytable`.`mycol`, substring_index(`mytable`.`mycol`,'http://',-1)
```

I still get these strings in the results:

```
https://111.com/
https://www.222.com/en-gb/
```

Why? since my query is looking for `http://` not `https://`, why do I get results start with `https://`? In this simple example, it should return nothing as there is no string starts with `http://`

want to extract the string

Answer (score 1):

use regex. Much more simpler.

SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE mycol REGEXP '^http://.+';

Comment: REGEXT to the best of my knowledge returns true or false. I need the part of string that starts with http:// but I need that part without http:// (i.e. substring)

Comment: in mysql version 8.0 theres REGEXP_SUBSTR. Might be a help

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract those that starts with http://

If you don't want want to use LIKE you can use [left()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
select right(columnname, length(columnname) - 7) from tablename
where left(columnname, 7) = 'http://'
```

You don't need to know the length of the string.
All you want is extract the part of the string after the 1st 7 chars.
The length of this part is:

```
length(columnname) - 7
```

So use [right()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right).

Comment: I need to understand what is the problem with sub_string in this example?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index. I guess `substring_index` is not the proper function to use in this case.

Comment: I want to etract the part after http:// (the substring without http://) that's why LIKE% is not suitable. And the length is not fixed. I have many strings. I just know their start but not thier length

Comment: So you can extract everything after the 1st 7 chars. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add check for delimeter:

```
SELECT `mycol`,
   IF(instr(mycol,'http://') > 0, substring_index(`mytable`.`mycol`,'http://',-1),NULL)
FROM mytable;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e2f25ef7e9688a0e3d4077e9674e2e7)**

---

When the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function cannot find delim string it will return original string instead of `NULL`.

```
SELECT substring_index('abc','.',-1)
=>
abc
```